# Google analytics visual counter

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a way to add a visual visitors counter to site, based on google analytics data? Something like photo added.[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to display the count of real-time users on the site, there is not a way as far as I'm aware.  If you want count of historical data, you can create report in Google Data Studio that can be embedded on your site.